# Change class property when set

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have the following class:

```
class Message {
    var content: [String]?

    init(content: [String]) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

I want `content` to be an array of Strings, that are always **uppercase**. Even when lowercase text is set to `content`. 
I don't seem to be able to use computed properties for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *property observer* `didSet` to apply `uppercased()` to the array when it is set:

```
class Message {
    var content: [String]? {
        didSet {
            if let arr = content {
                self.content = arr.map { $0.uppercased() }
            }
        }
    }

    init(content: [String]) {
        self.content = content.map { $0.uppercased() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have an internal variable storing the actual content and a computed property visible to the outside. If the public property is set, it computes the internal (uppercased) representation.

```
class Message {
    private var _content: [String]?
    var content: [String]? {
        get {
            return _content
        }
        set (new) {
            if let new = new {
                _content = new.map { $0.uppercased() }
            } else {
                _content = nil
            }
        }
    }

    init(content: [String]?) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

You can even assign `content` in the initializer and it will compute the upper case representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
init(content: [String]) {

    self.content =  content
    self.setupMyProperty()

 }

 func setupMyProperty() {
        let arrCaps = self.content.map{$0.uppercased()}

       self.content.removeAll() 
      self.content = arrCaps
    }
```

Comment: But what if I want to change `content` after initialization?

Comment: may b this is not right way but i think it will work.